# Unwanted spaces between the <tr> in my table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with my table. I have white spaces between the `<tr>` and I tried to put the cellpadding and cellspacing to 0, it didn't work. Then I also tried to put CSS inline in the `<table>` like this `style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:0"` but it didn't do anything so I am wondering what I did wrong.

```html
<div class="mcnTextContent">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
         <td><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/2c56d756-adcd-4e85-8a5e-b83721faf95c.png" width="100%"></td>
         <td><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/258d7fd6-b07f-416e-9439-de6a3aa18a4f.png" width="100%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
             <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/10c35c2e-1995-4559-803a-a4513059dfbd.png" width="100%">
            </td>
            <td>
             <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/41f2f947-4fed-4e6e-9a60-efa23445c5fd.png" width="100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
             <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/0cb1f251-81e8-4970-b006-bfad3ca6471e.png" width="100%">
            </td>
            <td>
             <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/170e33a3-4553-4068-b50d-58ec7ad115ca.png" width="100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
             <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/ca86c184-f61d-46e7-9a4b-9d0f41d4865a.png" width="100%">
            </td>
            <td>
             <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/798ce3296ef9c5b21143e2de6/images/fdfd9e56-d2ad-4eaa-96ad-b46dc3e70b80.png" width="100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because images are `inline`. Make them `block` and spaces will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code as external CSS file:

```
* {
    display: block;
}
tr, td {
    float: left;
}
```